# How to use TempData in ASP.NET Core React application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I have created an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application in React.

I am trying to use `TempData` in a controller action method. But I get an error saying

> TempData does not exists in current context

How can I use it?

Comment: Please add some code here we can't get your question properly

Comment: @BipilRaut, I want something like ```TempData["EmailId"] = viewModel.EmailAddress;``` But I get an error: _TempData does not exists in current context'_.

Comment: Hi @Dyantest,I think you need check the controller if it inherits `Controller`.If you inherits `ControllerBase`,it will give such error.

Comment: Hello @Rena, Yes. You are right. It inherits ```ControllerBase```. Because it is an api controller. Can you help me that how to use ```TempData``` in Api controller.(My project is in ```ReactJS```).

Comment: Hi @Dyantest,`Controller` inherits from `ControllerBase`,so `Controller` have all what `ControllerBase` have.I think change ControllerBase to Controller is a better way.Check my answer below.

Comment: @Dyantest  why would an API controller need TempData? There's no view to use it. I suspect you're trying to solve a different problem and assumed `TempData` is the solution. What's the *real* problem? Are you looking for `Session` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Controller` inherits from `ControllerBase`,so `Controller` have all what `ControllerBase` have.I think change `ControllerBase` to `Controller` is a better way.

You could check the source code below:

```
public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IFilterMetadata, IAsyncActionFilter, IDisposable
{
    protected Controller();

    public dynamic ViewBag { get; }
    
    [ViewDataDictionary]
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }

    public ITempDataDictionary TempData { get; set; }

    public void Dispose();

    //....
}
```

If you must use `ControllerBase`.Here is a working demo about how to use `TempData` in api controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{      
    private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;
    public ValuesController(ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
    {
        _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void Get()
    {
        var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(HttpContext);
        tempData["EmailId"] = "adasd";
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

Still repeat what i did in `Get` method and Get tempData in other action like below:

```
var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(HttpContext);
var data = tempData["EmailId"];
```

Comment: thanks. But can you suggest how to access ```tempData["EmailId"]``` in another Action Method.

Comment: An API doesn't need `TempData`. There's no view to receive the values stored there